# How to run portable utorrent and xbmc live simultaneously from usb flash drive

Tags: utorrent, kodi, usb-flash-drive

I have XBMC Live installed on a USB that I can boot directly in to on my laptop. Is it possible for me to run a version of portable utorrent simultaneously with the XBMC Live on the USB and set it up so that it downloads stuff while I watch pre-saved content on XBMC?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I have XBMC Live installed on a Zotac MAG, so I'm not running it off the USB key. I haven't tried this... it shouldn't hurt anything, but i'm not sure if it'll persist between reboots or not.

You might be able to run `apt-get install utorrent` from a console on the XBMC machine when booted off the key.  You'll need to use `ctrl-alt-F1` - `ctrl-alt-F6` to change TTYs to an available console.  the user and password should be xbmc/xbmc.

[Here](http://boshdirect.com/blogs/tech/how-to-install-sabnzbd-on-xbmc-live.html) is a site that describes how to do something similar with SABnzbd+.  You might be able to extrapolate some more data from it.